# robots.txt не могу найти ошибку

Tags: robots.txt

Проверяю `robots.txt` через Яндекс и он выдает кучу непонятных ошибок такого рода
`Правило начинается не с символа '/' и не с символа '*'` вот сам код:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Crawl-delay: 2
Disallow: loca.kg/user/login
Disallow: http://loca.kg/result
Disallow: http://loca.kg/cabinet
Disallow: http://loca.kg/user/login
Disallow: http://loca.kg/user/userlogin
Disallow: http://loca.kg/user/usercabinet
Disallow: http://loca.kg/user/register
Disallow: http://loca.kg/center
Disallow: http://loca.kg/centerlist
Sitemap: http://loca.kg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В правиле `disallow` не нужно указывать полный путь с протоколом:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Crawl-delay: 2
Disallow: /user/login
Disallow: /result
Disallow: /cabinet
Disallow: /user/login
Disallow: /user/userlogin
Disallow: /user/usercabinet
Disallow: /user/register
Disallow: /center
Disallow: /centerlist
```

А вот для sitemap нужно указать полный путь, например:

```
Sitemap: http://loca.kg/sitemap.xml
```